# Dependencies and local package not available when building notebooks in GitHub actions workflow

Tags: python, github-actions, python-poetry, papermill

I am getting back to Python but new to poetry and papermill.

We have repository hosted on GitHub which is a Python package with `pyproject.toml` which is private, once public and if this issue persists, will provide URL. We also have some notebooks in the same repo.

The steps are simply:

```
# installs package successfully but in an env
poetry install -E all
# run papermill under poetry 
poetry run papermill SomeNotebook.ipynb output_folder/file.txt
# same issues for
papermill SomeNotebook.ipynb output_folder/file.txt
```

When trying to build the notebooks using [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) I cannot:

1. Get the package dependencies to be available during the builds
2. Get the local package itself to be available during the builds

As requested in comment, the error is simply:

```
# for deps
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import pandas as pd
```

and exactly the same for the local package:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from mypackage.plots import *
```

The `poetry install -E all` in the workflow apprently installs the package itself and its dependencies in an env and requires `poetry shell`. But doing `poetry shell` is not [possible](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/3526#discussioncomment-4281606) as I get `Inappropriate ioctl for device`. I have tried activating the `env` via `source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate`, and tried `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` I get the same errors.

Can you help me build the notebooks with both deps and local/current package available during papermill step?

Thank you

Comment: I guess you need to edit your question and copy-paste the command output including the error message if any.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer but a solution. What we decided to use is to avoid `poetry` and use `pip`. I will leave the question there for in case the right answer comes.

So the above code is now:

```
# installs deps & package
pip install -e '.[all]'
# run papermill directly
papermill SomeNotebook.ipynb output_folder/file.txt
# passed github actions
```